# Tagging EMR cluster via an AWS Lambda tiggered by a Cloudwatch event rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, emr, amazon-emr, amazon-cloudwatch

I need to catch the event RunflowJob in my Cloudwatch EventRule in order to tag AWS EMR starting clusters.

I'm looking for this event, because i need the username and account informations

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Calls to the ListClusters, DescribeCluster, and RunJobFlow actions generate entries in CloudTrail log files.

Every log entry contains information about who generated the request. For example, if a request is made to create and run a new job flow (RunJobFlow), CloudTrail logs the user identity of the person or service that made the request

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/logging_emr_api_calls.html#understanding_emr_log_file_entries

Here is a sample snippet to get the username using Python Boto3.

```
import boto3
cloudtrail = boto3.client("cloudtrail")
response = cloudtrail.lookup_events (
    LookupAttributes=[
        {
            'AttributeKey': 'EventName',
            'AttributeValue': 'RunJobFlow'
        }
    ],
)
for event in response.get ("Events"):
    print(event.get ("Username"))
```

Answer (score 0):

username and cluster details can be retrieved from the RunJobFlow event itself. Easier solution would be to use Cloudwatch event rule along with Lambda function as a target to fetch these info and subsequently further action can be taken as required. Example below:

Event Pattern to be used with Cloudwatch event rule

```
{
"source": ["aws.elasticmapreduce"],
"detail": {
    "eventName": ["RunJobFlow"]
}
}
```

Lambda code snippet

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    #print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))
    user = event['detail']['userIdentity']['userName']
    cluster_id = event['detail']['responseElements']['jobFlowId']
    region = event['region']
```